# Setting up DNS MX Entry on Digital Ocean

Tags: email, digital-ocean

I want to use DO as my DNS Server. For emails I use 1and1 and I setup the Nameserver Configuration in the Domain control panel to use the DO Nameserver.

In DO I added an MX entry:

[image]

But is this the correct way? If I use one of my email I set up, do I need to configure it differently? If I send an email, nothing is being received in my inbox. For example the mail test@isarfaktor.de

How do I need to configure DO to handle emails with 1and1 properly?

Thank you

Comment: where are your mail hosted with 1&1 OR other hosting provider OR you have own mail server hosted?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned the Operating system of your Virtual Private Server.
First, you have to setup your server using postfix if you follow my method.

Approx 29% of public mail servers on the internet run very popular opensource mail transfer agent **Postfix**.Its helps to route and deliver email on a Linux system.

1. Make sure you have set up the domain with the ip already.
2. Now install post fix

```css
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

it will ask for domain name put your domain like this - farukkadir.com without any prefix like www.

now you have to edit postfix config by put this command

```html
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

find myhostname = something.com and edit with your domain

If you would like to configuring mail to be forwarded to other domains or wish to deliver to addresses that don't map 1-to-1 with system accounts, you can remove the alias_maps parameter and replace it with virtual_alias_maps. We would then need to change the location of the hash to /etc/postfix/virtual:

```html
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

and to get a webui install open source [squirrel mail -](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/clients/installing-squirrelmail-on-ubuntu-12-04)

If you still need help just comment here